# Including same Makefile from other makefiles

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to work with a hierarchy of Makefiles. Using GNU Make.

Lets say, I have a directory SRC which has 3 sub directories: A, B and C.

Every directory has it's own Makefile (Make.SRC, Make.A, Make.B and Make.C).

Both Make.B and Make.C need to use Make.A for some shared files.

In the Make.SRC file of SRC directory, I have the following lines:

```
include A/Make.A
include B/Make.B
include C/Make.C
```

But since I have multiple include of Make.A (a total of 3 times), it's giving me warnings for overriding commands for the targets inside Make.A .

What should be the way to work this kind of hierarchical Makefiles?
Is there any technique like C header files to avoid repeated include?

Comment: Are the individual sub-directory makefiles intended to be used standalone? That is can they be run directly and not through the toplevel Make.SRC?

Comment: Can't u use an ifdef like one uses in c include files?

Comment: @EtanReisner For Make.A yes. For Make.B or Make.C, need to use Make.A. I would like to go through Make.SRC so that I can do everything from the SRC directory.

Comment: If the individual makefiles aren't intended to be used on their own (I mean with `make -f Make.B <targets>` or whatever and only intended to be used as `make -f Make.SRC <targets>` then just don't include `Make.A` in `Make.B` or `Make.C` and let `Make.SRC` handle it.

Comment: @PaintedBlack I tried to use ifdef. Like- ifndef MAKE_A define MAKE_A endef <everything from original Make.A> endif . Got the same warnings. Not sure if I used it right.

Comment: @EtanReisner Nice suggestion! It works if I don't need to use those on their own.

Comment: What do the include lines in `Make.B` and `Make.C` for `Make.A` look like? `include ../A/Make.A`? `include A/Make.A`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry. I just noticed this comment. It's like `include $(SRCdir)/A/Make.A` .

Comment: Where `SRCdir` is set in `Make.SRC` (from `$(CURDIR)` or something like that)? Then the most recent edit of my answer should work (assuming the base make file names don't collide) but if you don't need this ability at all just don't include the other sub-makefiles in the sub-makefiles.

Comment: SRCdir is set with absolute path for now (/home/user/...). Yes. I am trying to analyze whether I can remove this ability altogether or not. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to be able to use the individual makefiles on their own `make -f Make.B <targets>` or `make -f Make.C <targets>` you could add a check for whether `Make.A` is in `$MAKEFILE_LIST` already or not and include it only if it isn't.

```
define condinc
    $(eval # Space needed after eval for this to function correctly.
    ifeq (,$(filter %$1,$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
        include $1
    endif
    )
endef
```

In `Make.SRC`:

```
$(call condinc,A/Make.A)
```

In `Make.B` or `Make.C`

```
$(call condinc,../A/Make.A)
```

Edit: Hm... no that's not going to work quite right. It'll need some tweaking to separate the path from the makefile name for the filter and include parts. Working on it.

If none of the basenames of the makefiles are going to match then using `ifeq (,$(filter %$(notdir $1),$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))` in that define mostly works. If they do then more changes to that function are necessary. But what exactly depends on what the sub-makefile include lines look like I think.

```
$ more {Makefile,{A,B,C}/Make.*} | cat
::::::::::::::
Makefile
::::::::::::::
define condinc
    $(eval
    ifeq (,$(filter %$(notdir $1),$(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
        include $1
    endif
    )
endef

$(info one)
$(call condinc,A/Make.A)
$(info two)
$(call condinc,B/Make.B)
$(info three)
$(call condinc,C/Make.C)
$(info four)
::::::::::::::
A/Make.A
::::::::::::::
$(info Make.A included)
$(info MAKEFILE_LIST is $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
::::::::::::::
B/Make.B
::::::::::::::
$(info Make.B included)
$(info MAKEFILE_LIST is $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

$(call condinc,$(CURDIR)/A/Make.A)
::::::::::::::
C/Make.C
::::::::::::::
$(info Make.C included)
$(info MAKEFILE_LIST is $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

Running with the above gets you:

```
$ make
one
Make.A included
MAKEFILE_LIST is  Makefile A/Make.A
two
Make.B included
MAKEFILE_LIST is  Makefile A/Make.A B/Make.B
three
Make.C included
MAKEFILE_LIST is  Makefile A/Make.A B/Make.B C/Make.C
four
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it and mark this as an answer once verified. Where do I put this function?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to test the solution. It's not passing the test for once. My output is `$ make
one
two
three
four`
Did I miss anything? I just copied and pasted the content to the files.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you include the `:::` lines in the makefiles? (They don't belong there; they are spit out by `more` as separators.) Are those filenames correct for your sub-directory makefiles?

Comment: No errors, other than "make: *** No targets.  Stop.". I didn't include the `:::` lines. I was concerned with the path though. But when I added the line `include A/Make.A`, it did show the two extra lines from Make.A. So, the path should be correct. Did any punctuation go missing from the definition because of copying-pasting?

Comment: Ah, yes, my apologies. A trailing space is needed on the eval line. I'll fix the post.